Did the death of the High Priest atone for sin and cleanse the land?
I have been studying up on Numbers 35, where it describes the issue of manslaughter and murder. If someone commits murder then they had to be put to death, but if it is found to be an accident (or perhaps there is just insufficient testimony) then the man-slaughterer could live out his days in one of the designated Cities of Refuge. There was no sacrifice or other payment that could redeem the life of the man-slaughterer.
Despite it being an accident, the act of shedding another man's blood is still worthy of death - it still defiles the land; even the land of Israel where God was said to dwell among the people. Under the Noahide Covenant (Genesis 9), any time that a man killed another man (unlawfully), regardless of intentions or the presence of any animosity, it was required of society that they put that man to death:
Genesis 9:6

Whoever sheds human blood,
By man his blood shall be shed,
For in the image of God
He made mankind.

Numbers 35:30-34

If anyone kills a person, the murderer shall be put to death on the testimony of witnesses, but no person shall be put to death on the testimony of only one witness. 31 Moreover, you shall not accept a ransom for the life of a murderer who is condemned to death, but he must be put to death. 32 And you shall not accept a ransom for one who has fled to his city of refuge, so that he may return to live in the land before the death of the priest. 33 So you shall not defile the land in which you live; for blood defiles the land, and no atonement can be made for the land for the blood that is shed on it, except by the blood of the one who shed it. 34 So you shall not defile the land in which you live, in the midst of which I dwell; for I the Lord am dwelling in the midst of the sons of Israel.

The idea of the shedding of human blood defiling the land hearkens back to when Cain slew Abel:
Genesis 4:9-12

Then the Lord said to Cain, “Where is Abel your brother?” And he said, “I do not know. Am I my brother’s keeper?” 10 Then He said, “What have you done? The voice of your brother’s blood is crying out to Me from the ground. 11 Now you are cursed from the ground, which has opened its mouth to receive your brother’s blood from your hand. 12 When you cultivate the ground, it will no longer yield its strength to you; you will be a wanderer and a drifter on the earth.”

Under the Law, the avenger of blood referred to the one who took on the role of killing a man-slaughterer (though the scriptures don't go into detail as far as selecting who this was as far as I can tell). Despite that this was a role that God requires of society, God also established the Cities of Refuge to show mercy to those who didn't kill intentionally or out of malice. And, what is more, upon the death of the High Priest all of the man-slaughterers were seemingly forgiven; they could return home without fear of being put to death by the avenger of blood, and with no more need to cleanse the land through their blood.
Numbers 35:25-28

And the congregation shall save the one who committed manslaughter from the hand of the blood avenger, and the congregation shall return him to his city of refuge to which he fled; and he shall live in it until the death of the high priest who was anointed with the holy oil. 26 But if at any time he goes beyond the border of his city of refuge to which he flees, 27 and the blood avenger finds him outside the border of his city of refuge, and the blood avenger kills him, he will not be guilty of bloodshed, 28 because he should have remained in his city of refuge until the death of the high priest. But after the death of the high priest the one who committed manslaughter may return to the land of his property.

To get to my question then, I wanted to know how this phenomenon is understood within Judaism: did the life of the High Priest serve to atone for / cleanse the man-slaughterers? Did the High Priest's death serve to cleans the land? Or is something else going on here altogether? If not atonement, is there another term that would be used to describe this?

You bring a very interesting idea to the table! As far as I know, it is not discussed in traditional sources, see here for the explanations our commentators have come up with: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9417/why-do-accidental-killers-sent-to-arei-miklat-go-free-after-the-kohen-gadol-dies

You seem to be asking two questions here: (a) in what way does the High Priest's death affect the man-slaughterer(s) (where you suggest atonement by blood as an answer), and (b) what happens to one who accidentally kills the High Priest. They should probably be asked separately.

"[D]id the blood of the High Priest serve to atone for / cleanse the man-slaughterers? Did the High Priest's blood serve to cleans the land?" When blood atones, it is the [figurative] spilling of the blood that atones, i.e. the killing that atones. The High Priest is not executed, and in most cases not even killed by Heaven, but usually would die of natural causes, like old age. So, though his death might atone, I don't see how his unspilled blood would.

@TamirEvan I revised the question based upon your feedback; thanks. I'm not sure I agree with the idea that it is the killing that atones, however. Rather, scripture asserts that the life of a creature is in its blood. It isn't the act of killing that atones so much as the life in the shed blood. That said - if you have references that backup the idea that is the act of killing specifically that atones I'd be interested.
